# PythonによるNW機器の情報取得時のエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, network

初めまして。初めて質問させていただきます。お手柔らかにお願い致します。

**問題点**

net_connect.send_commandメソッドにて `sh run` のコマンドを送信したときのみ、下記エラーとなり情報が出力されません。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

他のコマンド、`sh ver` や `sh ip int bri` 等は問題なく出力可能です。

**コード**

```
import netmiko

cisco_ios = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "ipアドレス",
    "username": "ユーザー名",
    "password": "パスワード",
    "port": 22,
    "secret": "enableパスワード",
    "verbose": False,
}

net_connect = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**cisco_ios)

print("--------------------",cisco_ios['ip'],"--------------------")
output = net_connect.send_command("sh run")
print(output)
```

浅識で申し訳ないのですが、解決法をお教え願えませんでしょうか。
質問内容に不備が御座いましたら、ご指摘のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: Python のライブラリ側の問題かネットワーク機器側の問題かは切り分けられているのでしょうか？　たとえば、このライブラリを介さずに直接機器に対して `sh run` した場合はエラーなく出力されますか？

Comment: 実行したそれぞれのコマンドは省略形のようですが、省略せずに `show running-config` 入力した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: Privileged exec mode(enable mode) に切り替える必要があるのではないでしょうか。具体的には `net_connect.enable()` を実行してから `net_connect.send_command("sh run")` を実行します。